# Ansible setup for mysql

Tags: ansible

I am learning ansible and I am basically setting up my ec2 server with ansible and is installing mysql on another ec2 server. The objective is to create a user Bob with pw 12345.

```
  - hosts: database
  sudo: yes

  tasks:
    - name: Install mySQL repo
      yum: name=http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el7-8.noarch.rpm state=present

    - name: Install mySQL
      yum: pkg={{ item }}
      with_items:
        - mysql-community-server
        - mysql-community-client
        - MySQL-python

    - name: start mySQL service
      action: service name=mysqld state=started

    - name: copy my.cnf
      template: src=.my.cnf dest=/root/.my.cnf owner=root mode=0600

    - name: Create database user
      mysql_user: name=bob password=12345 priv=*.*:ALL state=present login_user=root login_password=Password123_#
```

this is my.cnf file:

```
[client]
user=root
password=Password123_#
```

Currently, this is my ansible playbook which I have done but i keep getting a

```
fatal: [FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "unable to connect to database, check login_user and login_password are correct or /root/.my.cnf has the credentials. Exception message: (1045, \"Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)\")"}
        to retry, use: --limit @/etc/an
```

Can I have some advice what I am doing wrong?

PS: im not a mySQL expert but am learning.

Comment: Both *login_password* and *login_user* are missing in the *mysql_user:* task.

Comment: Are you able to connect from the command-line? Is this an Ansible or MySQL question?

Answer (score 1):

What you try to do is defining credentials for a new user without credentials for mysql connection.

As stated [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/mysql_user_module.html) either `login_user` & `login_password` or credentials in a file `~/.my.cnf` is required to add or delete a user with `mysql_user` module.

> Both login_password and login_user are required when you are passing credentials. If none are present, the module will attempt to read the credentials from ~/.my.cnf, and finally fall back to using the MySQL default login of ‘root’ with no password.

Comment: Thank you so much Akif. I did as instructed and I have updated my post with suggested but still im getting the error. I copied my customer .my.cnf file over so that I will know the password.